# Prove $\lim b_{n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}b_{n}=0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=1$. Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_{n}=0$

My approach: since $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}b_{n}=0$ and  $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=1$, by the limit laws of sequences, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n}b_{n}}{a_{n}}=\frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}b_{n}}{\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}}=\frac{0}{1}=0$. But since $0=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n}b_{n}}{a_{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} b_{n}$, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_{n}=0$.

But what I want is an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what you did before:
$$
|b_n| = \frac{|a_n b_n|}{|a_n|} < \frac{\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon}{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
provided that $|a_n| > 1/2$ and $|a_n b_n| < \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$. But both conditions are surely true if $n$ is large enough, since $a_n \to 1 > 1/2$ and $a_n b_n \to 0$.

Comment: But how to demonstrate there exists an N such that for all n>N 0.5<|a|? stuck there

Comment: Pick $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ in the definition of $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n = 1$.

Comment: AH i see. im boggled by stupid triangle inequalities. thanks :)

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, you should accept it or, at least, upvote it...